# MKTileOverlay with MTiles database

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mktileoverlay

Is there a way to use the [MKTileOverlay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay) with a [MBTiles](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec) database? Storing many small files (tiles) directly on the native file system is very inefficient when the covered area is getting bigger. Having them all together in one place would make a lot easier. However, I cannot find any information on how to use `MBTiles` with the `MKtileOverlay`.

Answer (score 1):

There's an old Git repository that you may be able to use. It hasn't been updated in years, so I don't know how reliable it is, but for what this is worth, check it out: https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/tree/issue3-mbtiles/MBXMapKit